# Getting the Pusher JS client working in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, phantomjs, pusher

I'm having an issue with getting the Pusher client to connect when using PhantomJS during selenium testing. The library never makes it out of connecting.

Console Log:

```
Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting (undefined:undefined)
Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws.pusherapp.com:443/app/8f2c58afe761d56c83dc?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"} (undefined:undefined)
binded (undefined:undefined)
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> unavailable (undefined:undefined)
Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws.pusherapp.com:443/app/8f2c58afe761d56c83dc?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"} (undefined:undefined)
Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws.pusherapp.com:443/app/8f2c58afe761d56c83dc?protocol=7&client=js&version=3.0.0&flash=false"} (undefined:undefined)
```

[Here](http://github.com/beal/pusher-phantom) is a small project in Django that is exhibiting the issue.

Comment: Hey Kevan, are you able to share a sample project that has this problem so we can recreate it?

Comment: Hi Jack, here is a repository with a small Django project that exhibits the issue.  https://github.com/beal/pusher-phantom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like PhantomJS has some issues with websockets. These issues are fixed in 2.0. Installing phantomjs 2.0 fixed the issue.